# How to disable Proxy for Axios Nest JS Project?

Tags: javascript, proxy, nestjs

I was trying to disable Proxy for localhost in my Nestjs Project, I am using Axios to call API.

Is there any way to disable proxy in my AXIOS call ?

```js
const requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER',
  },
  proxy:false,
};

const responseData = await lastValueFrom(
  this.httpService.post(requestUrl, data, requestConfig).pipe(
    map((response) => {
      return response.data;
    }),
  ),
);
```

Above code is it giving error

Comment: IMO, proxy should be disabled by default

Comment: @SiddharthSathe: Nope, Axios pickup the proxy from process.env.HTTP_PROXY